# is it possible to show the link in address bar of another site in my site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm in quite a strange problem. one of my clients want to show the data of another site in his site. i have a link of the other site, he wants that when the user clicks in that link, he will be redirected to another page of his own website but will show the content of that link. i did this using iframe but now he want, the address bar will have to show the link of that content. when the users will click on it, they will redirect to another page of my clients website but will show the content of the other site, also show the link of the other site in the address bar. i don't know even if it is possible or not. Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: No; what's in the address bar is the address of the current page. If he wants the address of the other site in the address bar, and the contents of that site on the page? *Send the user to that site.*

Comment: hmmmmm iframe is the best opt need little jquery to go along with! but its a bad idea as well

Comment: That's not how internet works.

Comment: can have url params set that you map in your back end code to determine which url to dislay in iframe

Comment: I think the best you can do is have a url like http://www.example.org?impersonate=http://www.someothersite.org and have the iframe cover the whole page.

Comment: Time to get a better client.

Comment: $file = file_get_contents('anothersite.com');

Comment: @artm can u tell me, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to: Can I have the address bar lie to the user by saying they're on Site A but actually having them on Site B?

No, modulo browser bugs (and I'm not aware of any). And if it were possible, it would be **extremely** inappropriate. (You can get close, with an off-by-one domain name or similar, but again: **extremely** inappropriate.)

Sometimes we just have to say "no" to clients. This is one of those times.

Comment: yes,,,you are right,,,,That's exactly i'm going to tell him...i don't want to be a part of anything illegal... :/ Thanks... :) :)

Answer (score -1):

To be short, Yes you can do it. This would require the HTML5 history API, see this snippet.

```
history.pushState({},"Name","URL");
```

Some sites have safeguards against this, like StackOverflow.

The question then becomes **SHOULD** you do it. The answer would likely be NO. This would make it possible, and I've already see people do this, to fake google or your banking-environment. 
I don't know your customer, but when people start asking for such specific things, there is likely to be something wrong

Comment: No, there are limits to `pushState`, including checking of origin. You can't just use `pushState` to push an arbitrary URL with a different origin on your page. If you try, you'll get an exception like `Exception: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://www.google.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://example.com'.` Try it here, for instance (farsightsoftware.com is doing **nothing** special to prevent it): http://farsightsoftware.com/temp/pushstate.html

Comment: Didn't know that, the weird thing however is that a classmate of mine has done it, this might then be a bug in chromium.